# Argument out of range exception, Parameter name : name

Tags: c#, linq, fastmember

Each time trying to execute the following code with different rows; getting the same exception :

```
 var result = (from prod in context.ProductsTbls
                          join img in context.ProductImagesTbls
                          on prod.Id equals img.ProductId
                          where prod.UserId == 4 && img.IsDefaultImage ==true
                          select new
                          {                            
                              Image = img.Image
                          }).ToList();


            IEnumerable<Object> data = result.ToList();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data , "Image"))
            {
                table.Load(reader); // Exception appears here
            }
```

And getting this exception :

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: name'
```

Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: @JohnWu For what is it important to solve my issue?

Comment: What is this `ObjectReader`? Showing the stack trace might have revealed that. If it's some third-party thing it's probably got a bug.

Comment: @GertArnold This is the so-called "Fast member" I use it in order to put the data into DataTable class, it has nothing to do with a third party.

Comment: The `Load()` method, which threw the exception, does not have a parameter named `name`. So if that is the error, we need to see what internal call threw the exception originally, so we can tell what parameter validation rule isn't being satisfied. Please post the stack trace.

Comment: Fast-Member. Made by Marc Gravell: I revoke what I said about the likelihood of bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're using a third-party library, [Fast-Member](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member) which is aimed at dynamically accessing type members way faster than reflection.

The problem is that you cast your collection to `IEnumerable<Object>`, so all type information is gone and the member name `Image` can't be found.

Just remove this cast, it's useless. You can remove the line `IEnumerable<Object> data = result.ToList();` entirely and offer `result` to `ObjectReader`.

Comment: How I couldn't note this, Thanks man it works, I did exactly as you suggest.